# I can connect to a google cloud deployed mongoDB from localhost but not from the same app when deploying on the app engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

My app is written in React and Express using Mongoose for the db. I deployed a bitnami mongoDB instance on google compute engine. Now I'm trying to deploy the server on the App engine. When I run my app locally it connects fine to the db (I can add stuff and see it). But when I do an npm start in the google cloud shell is get this error:

```
'failed to connect to server [35.196.182.249:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to 35.196.182.249:27017 timed out]' }
(node:1310) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): MongoError: failed to connect to server [35.196.182.249:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to 35.196.182.249:27017 timed out]
```

Here is my code to connect:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI,{
    useMongoClient: true
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err)
});
```

where `MONGODB_URI=mongodb://root:password@XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:27017`,
 `password` is the password I got from the compute engine, and `XX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is the external IP provided by the compute engine.
 I use the same URI when connecting locally and in the google cloud shell but it only connects from localhost. I tried hardcoding in the URI too and it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you a[llow access to the port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/using-firewalls) from the external IP on the compute engine instance? Did you specify the [`bindIP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) in the mongod config for the instance? Because logic says the compute instance would require you to allow access explicitly rather than be "open to the world" and the `mongod` defaults are to `127.0.0.1` by default for the same reason.

Comment: I haven't done that so that is almost certainly it. Sorry I'm new to all this. You bind the IP of your server right? But if I'm deploying my server and it tries to connect it will run and fail to connect before I know the IP address to bind to, what's my knowledge gap there?

Comment: You can bind to the `0.0.0.0` IP and by default will allow everybody to connect to it.

Comment: @colinlmacleod1Hi Colin. Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @NeilLunn my mongodb uri doesn't refer to one hosted with Google Compute Engine, yet I'm having this issue. Mongoose on my app engine instance keeps timing out, but I can connect fine on my local machine.

Comment: I think Bitnami automatically only allows the first IP address that requests to access it unless you explicitly change the firewall settings. I fixed it by making a new bitnami mongo instance on GCE and connecting to it from my app first instead of from local host. That worked for me

Comment: @colinlmacleod1 gotcha, thanks. My mongodb is hosted by mlab and I can connect to it just fine from my laptop or a DigitalOcean droplet. App Engine however times out for whatever reason, so the issue is app engine side, not db side. Thanks for responding again.